# How to prove P(y|D,x)=∫P(y|f,D,x)P(D,f)df

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

In my probabilistic machine learning notes, it is stated that:
\begin{equation}
P(y|D,x)=\int P(y|f,D,x)P(D,f) df
\end{equation}
However I am unsure how to evaluate the right hand equation to prove this.

For context: This would be for a classification with y representing each class. D is your test datum and x is the training data set. f is your predictive function, f:x->y

The equation is copied correctly from my notes and it is just the math I am struggling with.

Comment: Assuming that $P(\cdot)$ represents a probability density function, it seems like an odd representation. Since $f$ is being integrated out, it seems that integrand is the joint conditional density, $p(y, f | D,x)$, which can be factorized as $$p(y, f | D,x) = p(y | f, D, x) p(f | D, x).$$

Comment: Do you have a source that your notes come from? A textbook, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

It is incorrect, it should be
\begin{equation}
P(y|D,x)=\int P(y|f,D,x)P(f|D,x) df
\end{equation}
which simplifies into
\begin{equation}
P(y|D,x)=\int P(y|f,D,x)P(f|D) df
\end{equation}
if $f$ only depends on $D$